# SQL Server: Recovery model effect on TempDB

Tags: sql-server, tempdb, recoverymodel

Does the recovery model of a database effect the size of the tempdb.mdf?

We have a database which involves a lot of processing and bulk inserts. We are having problems with the tempdb file growing to extremely large sizes (over 70 gb). The database in question is set to Full Recovery. Will changing it to Simple Recovery(on the database with all the transactions not the tempdb) prevent it from using the tempdb on these large inserts and bulk loads?

Comment: Do you have the tempdb recovery model set to simple? That's what MS recommend here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175527(SQL.90).aspx

Comment: Yes the tempdb itself is already set to simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recovery mode of the database doesn't affect its use of tempdb. The tempdb usage is most likely from the 'processing' part: static cursors, temp tables and table variables, sort operations and other worktable backed query operators, large variables and parameters.

The bulk insert part (ie. the part which would be affected by the recovery mode) has no tempdb impact.

Answer (score 1):

### tempdb Size and Placement Recommendations

To achieve optimal tempdb performance, we recommend the following configuration for tempdb in a production environment:

Set the recovery model of tempdb to SIMPLE. This model automatically reclaims log space to keep space requirements small.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175527.aspx